# can I re initialize a variable after proceeding the code at python

Tags: python

I want to make a program that takes some information from a user and gives them a certain value that has `increased` by a certain amount from the last time the program was `run`.

So to give an example:

- `x = 1`
- the user `inputs` something and `"2"` is `printed`
- they close the `program`
- the user `inputs` something and `"3"` is `printed`
- they close the `program`
- the user `inputs` something and `"4"` is `printed`
- so on...

Is this even possible in `Python`?

Comment: please post your code

Comment: You'll have to persist the count outside of the program and update it as needed in some way. If it's just a single number, you could probably get away with a text file. Anything more than that and you'll want a database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, create a file named something like `data.txt` in the same directory as your `.py` `file` with just the value `0` in it.

Then in your `.py` `file`, you could do something like:

```
curNum = int(open("data.txt", "r").read())

toAdd = int(input("number to add: "))

newNum = curNum + toAdd

print("number is now:", newNum)

open("data.txt", "w").write(str(newNum))
```

---

So after creating the `file`: `data.txt` with content `0`, here is the result of some tests:

*1st run*

```
number to add: 10
number is now: 10
```

*2nd run*

```
number to add: 2
number is now: 12
```

*3rd run*

```
number to add: 8
number is now: 20
```

---

Hope you can apply this to what you want to do!

Comment: wow .. thank u very much you put me on the way .. I did it ..  you are so helpful